# Bounding box of an object in an image Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to get the object's bounding box positions (x, y, width and height) in the image and save it to a text file. As shown in the below image. So if anyone could please advise.
The image can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rywsg1f3sf6zhwv/Image0001.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have read the image using `imread`, this should work:

```
bwImage=~im2bw(img,0.98);  %making gray pixels white and (almost) white pixels black
bndBox=regionprops(bwImage,'BoundingBox');
```

`bndBox` will have top-left corner of the bounding box and its width and height stored in the format `[corner_x corner_y width height]`.

Comment: I have a problem now, sometimes regionprops return 3 bounding boxs, how to only get the biggest bounding box with the biggest width and height?

Comment: just to be clear, do you want the biggest bounding box out of those 3, or you want the bounding box enclosing those 3 boxes?

Comment: I need to use `regionprops` more often, this BoundingBox feature is very useful.

Comment: @chappjc I recommend you to look at the suite of minimal bounding boxes [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34767-a-suite-of-minimal-bounding-objects). This can find bounding rectangles, triangles, quadrilaterals etc. I have found it useful in my research.